# is it possible to call require from C

Tags: lua

I have a module compiled in a shared object (I followed the library part of this article https://chsasank.github.io/lua-c-wrapping.html) and I want to load it from C not from the interpreter.

Is it possible ? If so how to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, as `require` is a function stored in a global environment. Lua does the same in standalone interpreter when it needs to process the `-l` option, see the [`dolibrary`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lua.c.html#dolibrary) function.

You do this the same way as with any other global function - in simplest case calling lua_getglobal(), then pushing the name of the file to require, and calling lua_call/lua_pcall/whatever.

Comment: What's funny is that, you'd think that `luaL_requiref` would do the equivalent of what you're talking about. But it doesn't. Not unless the C function you provide handles the package machinery.

Comment: @NicolBolas, `luaL_requiref` does almost the equivalent of `require`. It skips the loader stuff since it's not relevant for a C function.

Comment: @lhf: But the "loader stuff" is, for the most part, why people use `require` to begin with. It's not like it's difficult to check to see if something is in a table, and to stick the result of the loader into that table if it isn't. The hard part is going through each of the `package.loader` possibilities and invoking them in sequence until one comes out correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, right now, I'm using Lua 5.1 and "dolibrary" function doesn't exist, I tried to take some part of the code and it crashes :\ So, for now, I use luaL_dostring(L, "require 'libMyWrappings'"); libMyWrappings must be in the same directory as the c program, and I can't use a path to indicate the lib.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I am late, but someone else may struggle with this right now (like I just did).
This is a simple way of doing "require" from C:
`int reqRes = luaL_dostring(L, "local t=require('myLib') return (t~=nil)");`
`if (reqRes==0)`
  `//success`
`else`
  `//failed`

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, right now, I'm using Lua 5.1 and "dolibrary" function doesn't exist, I >tried to take some part of the code and it crashes :\ So, for now, I use luaL_dostring(L, >"require 'libMyWrappings'"); libMyWrappings must be in the same directory as the c >program, and I can't use a path to indicate the lib. – Aminos Jan 22 at 11:45

I just ran into the same issue, it has to do when the package library is loaded
  {LUA_LOADLIBNAME, luaopen_package}
needs to happen before you try and call it